# The Lumen in The Strain

Tags: the-strain

Why does Prof Setrakian just not digitize or copy the Lumen, instead of spending so much time and effort in protecting it from theft and fire etc.?

Comment: Can you provide any research you've done in trying to find an answer for this? Maybe some more context? To expand on the question a little.

Comment: No solid research. I did a quick google and nothing turned up.  I've been watching The Strain since season 1 and I thought this was a plot hole.  Curious if anyone had any opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think part of the issue with simply taking a picture and/or digitizing the book pages is that they might miss something.  For example, in season 3, episode 5, "Madness" you may remember that Setrakian discovers the information he needs is watermark text hidden within the Lumen's page.  Specifically, the Master can be defeated by containing him in a silver-lined sarcophagus. If the page had been photographed and/or digitized, such a watermark would not likely have been found. Given that he found one such 'Easter Egg' Setrakian may well believe that other clues may be similarly hidden within the Lumen thus why he looks at it under many different circumstances to try to find what is hidden.

What lends credence to this theory is the fact the Lumen is encased in silver. What better way to prevent the strigoi from physically leafing through the Lumen to discover the hidden clues.  But, only by leafing through the book are such clues discoverable.

Comment: I had forgotten about the watermark.  Thanks for the trip down memory lane :)